# Suds (Python SOAP client) - unsupported operand type

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I am trying to work with **eBay Trading SOAP API**:

```
from suds.client import Client
print Client('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl')
```

and I get this:

```
ERROR:suds.servicedefinition:unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 245, in __unicode__
    return self.description()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 223, in description
    sig.append(self.xlate(p[1]))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 189, in xlate
    name += '[]'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4.1 (beta)  build: R705-20101207

unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

What is going on?

The **Finding API** works OK:

```
Client('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl')
```

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Comment: I get the same error while using version 0.4.0.

Comment: There is a ticket for this error: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/399.